# Hiding image view before animating it

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Image view, i am applying animation to it, it has to move up and down on the screen when the button is pressed. But before the button is pressed i want the image hidden.

I am using the following code:

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.aim);
        animation.reset();
maxName.startAnimation(animation);
```

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromYDelta="15%p"
    android:repeatCount="2"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toYDelta="60%p" />
```

What changes should i make in order to hide the image before the button is pressed.

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

`android:visibility="invisible"`

to your element in its xml file? You can also use `gone` instead of `invisible` if you want the element to occupy no space in your layout.

Then when the button is pressed, you can change the visibility of the element at runtime:

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.aim);
        animation.reset();
maxName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
maxName.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add AnimationListener to your animation  .. and write down

```
yourImageview.setvisibility(view.gone) in onAnimationStart
yourImageview.setvisibility(view.visible) in onAnimationEnd
```